# How can I produce the same/similar layout with the fonts in (La)TeX?

Tags: templates

The below document is from 1965 (scanned PDF) and I really like it. Any idea about producing this layout with the included fonts. I'm sorry for not being able to provide my own work about this as I'm very new to LaTeX.

[Document](https://www.ietlabs.com/pdf/GR_Appnote/IN-105%20Frequency%20Spectrum%20of%20a%20Tone%20Burst.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Hi! I marked your post as "needs more clarity" since your question is very broad. In addition, I added a screenshot of the document,

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates to get some ideas.

Comment: If you are very new to LaTeX then maybe don't start with a huge project like mimicking a special template, start small instead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I suggest https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner.

Comment: Are you asking about the fonts or the page layout?

Comment: If the problem is to find a similar font, start by the [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/)

Comment: @Fran I added your comment to my "answer" and mention your name.

Comment: Thx for all comments. Actually, I am asking for the layout with the fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange!

The typeface for the title (INSTRUMENT NOTES) is [Warren Chappell's Lydian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydian_(typeface)), first designed in 1938. The sans serif type is [Futura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)) designed (at least to start) by Paul Renner. For some strange reason, the two typefaces are found together rather more than one would expect.

Cheers.

Comment: +1: How do you know that? :)

Comment: I added Wikipedia links to the fonts, hope that is ok.

Comment: Never mind, just saw your profile saying "Also author of Fontographer: Type by design." :)

Comment: Thx @sgmoye! And for the links Dr. Kuehner...:)

Answer (score 1):

- In the title of your question you mention "typeface" (font).
- If you look at the document properties of the PDF then you see the following (also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919)). But I am not sure if these are the actual fonts since you mention that it is a scanned PDF.

[image]

- Or consider [Fran's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11604) comment: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/
- But if you are looking to re-create the layout etc., then I repeat my comments: **(1)** If you are very new to LaTeX then maybe don't start with a huge project like mimicking a special template, start small instead. **(2)** Maybe have a look at learners' material like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11).